# ¿Cómo ocultar contenidos de un producto ya adquirido?

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy realizando un proyecto de ecommerce de libros electrónicos, digitales, físicos, es una practica de la universidad.

Cuando el **usuario** ***inicia sesión*** En el perfil del usuario, el usuario puede ver sus productos adquiridos, pedidos completos o pedidos en progreso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el pedido completado, debajo del **Status** del estado `Completed` quiero mostrar el enlace de descarga del libro, solo si el pedido está completado, el enlace de descarga con una fecha de validación de 3 meses, luego de los 3 meses el enlace ya no este disponible.

En el detalle del producto, quiero ocultar el precio y el botón de añadir producto al carrito, en vez de ello quiero que se muestre el enlace de descarga del libro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el listado de los productos, el producto adquirido quiero ocultar el botón de añadir al carrito de la compra y mostrar solo el detalle y mostrar otro enlace de ver orden.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Código completo

**my_orders.php**

```
<table width="795" align="center" bgcolor="pink"> 

    <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="6"><h2>Your Orders details:</h2></td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center" bgcolor="skyblue">
        <th>S.N</th>
        <th>Product (S)</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Invoice No</th>
        <th>Order Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    include("includes/db.php");

  $user = $_SESSION['customer_email'];
  $get_c = "select * from customers where customer_email='$user'";
  $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $get_c);
  $row_c = mysqli_fetch_array($run_c);
    $c_id = $row_c['customer_id'];

    $get_order = "select * from orders where c_id='$c_id'";

    $run_order = mysqli_query($con, $get_order); 

    $i = 0;

    while ($row_order=mysqli_fetch_array($run_order)){

        $order_id = $row_order['order_id'];
        $qty = $row_order['qty'];
        $pro_id = $row_order['p_id'];
        $invoice_no = $row_order['invoice_no'];
        $order_date = $row_order['order_date'];
        $status = $row_order['status'];
        $i++;

        $get_pro = "select * from products where product_id='$pro_id'";
        $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro); 

        $row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro); 

        $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image']; 
        $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];

    ?>
    <tr align="center">
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $pro_title;?><br>
        <img src="../admin_area/product_images/<?php echo $pro_image;?>" width="50" height="50" />
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $qty;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $invoice_no;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $order_date;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $status;?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

**all_products.php**

```
<?php 
$get_pro = "select * from products";

$run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro); 

while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){

    $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
    $pro_cat = $row_pro['product_cat'];
    $pro_brand = $row_pro['product_brand'];
    $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
    $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
    $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];

    echo "
            <div id='single_product'>

                <h3>$pro_title</h3>

                <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='180' height='180' />

                <p><b> $ $pro_price </b></p>

                <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>Details</a>

                <a href='index.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><button style='float:right'>Add to Cart</button></a>

            </div>


    ";

}
?>
```

**details.php**

```
    <?php 
    if(isset($_GET['pro_id'])){

    $product_id = $_GET['pro_id'];

    $get_pro = "select * from products where product_id='$product_id'";

    $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro); 

    while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){

        $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
        $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
        $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
        $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];
        $pro_desc = $row_pro['product_desc'];

        echo "
                <div id='single_product'>

                    <h3>$pro_title</h3>

                    <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='400' height='300' />

                    <p><b> $ $pro_price </b></p>

                    <p>$pro_desc </p>

                    <a href='index.php' style='float:left;'>Go Back</a>

                    <a href='index.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><button style='float:right'>Add to Cart</button></a>

                </div>


        ";

    }
    }
?>
```

Base de datos **online_shop** tabla `customers`

```
customer_id     customer_name     customers_email     customer_pass
    5                Wali          wali@gmail.com        wali123
```

tabla `products`

```
 product_id     product_title     product_price     product_desc     product_image
    8           Pablo Neruda         450           Veinte poemas...    image.png
```

Tabla `orders`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

saludos, en el archivo details.php puedes hacer una consulta del estado del libro, y donde generas el html haces una condición para que salga el contenido que quieras, espero te ayude.

```
if($estado=="completed"){

  echo "tu html sin costo";
}

if($estado=="in Progress"){

  echo "tu html con costo";
}
```

Comment: Gracias es un buen ejemplo amigo, solo una pregunta como se haría la consulta para evitar algún error, porque los datos sólo se ocultarían cuando el usuario inicia sesión siempre en cuando aquel usuario tenga realizado un pedido ya sea un pedido completado o un pedido en proceso, la consulta debe ser entre la tabla usuario y la tabla orders verdad? me puedes dar un ejemplo la verdad tanto código me borrado la memoria :(

Comment: claro, cuando llegue a casa te puedo ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Viendo un poco por encima el código creo que lo mas optimo en este caso seria aplicar un **LEFT JOIN** con la tabla `orders`

**all_products.php**

```
<?php 
// Forzar $user a entero
$user = (int) $user;
// Construimos la consulta
$get_pro = "
SELECT 
    p.product_id,
    p.product_cat,
    p.product_brand,
    p.product_title,
    p.product_price,
    p.product_image,

    o.order_id,
    o.status,
    o.c_id,
    o.p_id
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN orders o ON p.product_id = o.p_id AND o.c_id = $user ";

$run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro); 

while($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){

    $pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];
    $pro_cat = $row_pro['product_cat'];
    $pro_brand = $row_pro['product_brand'];
    $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
    $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
    $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];

    // recuperamos los datos de orders, si no tiene seran NULL
    $pro_order_id = $row_pro['order_id'];
    $pro_status = $row_pro['status'];
    $pro_c_id = $row_pro['c_id'];
    $pro_p_id = $row_pro['p_id'];

    // creamos una cadena para almacenar el detalle
    $detalle = "<div id='single_product'>
                <h3>$pro_title</h3>
                <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='180' height='180' />
                <p><b> $ $pro_price </b></p>
                <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='float:left;'>Details</a>";
    // creamos un condicional para decidir el boton
    if($pro_status == 'completed'){
        $detalle .= "Boton para cuando el order es complete.";
    }
    elseif($pro_status == 'in Progress'){
        $detalle .= "Boton para cuando el order es in Progress.";
    }
    // cuando es NULL o otro estado que no coincide con los anteriores
    else{
        $detalle .= "<a href='index.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><button style='float:right'>Add to Cart</button></a>"
    }
    // concatenamos el cierre del div
    $detalle .= "</div>";

    // Imprimimos
    echo $detalle;
}

// cuando solo utilizamos codigo PHP es preferible no utilizar la etiqueta de cierre
//?>
```

Para `details.php` seria hacer básicamente lo mismo.